# Is it possible to add custom block attributes to the built in copy-paste styles function?

Tags: block-editor

Gutenberg Blocks offer the function to copy and paste styles between blocks. We extended some of the core blocks and added custom attributes.

Can the copy paste functionality be extended, so that theses attributes are also included when copy-paste is used?

Comment: this shouldn't be necessary and work automatically, do you have more information about this? Richtext formats don't need special steps to allow copy pasting, however if you have not used core richtext components and implemented your own system you would need to share what you've done for the question to be answerable. Likewise block attributes are not styles, so if you're referring to options in a sidebar then that heavily implies you've implemented something in a non-standard way. Please edit the question to include concrete examples and code

Comment: It for sure can, but this is not an easy task, since this involves tweaking default functioning of block editor, requiring advanced knowledge of block editor ecosystem and React. Alternatively, you can suggest that as an improvement on Gutenberg's github page.